# Retrieve POST data back AJAX / jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

`post.js`

```
$.post(
  "/scripts/update.php",
  {id: testId, age: testAge},
  function(data) {
    $(".testDiv").html(data.testId);
    $(".testDiv2").html(data.testAge);
  },
  "json"
);
```

`update.php`

```
$userId = $_POST["id"];
$userAge = $_POST["age"];

// contact database and retrieve user Id and user name...

echo json_encode(array("testId"=>$userId, "testAge"=>$userAge));
```

I if I were to take out the `, "json");` code I can pass information to the `update.php` just fine, but can not retrieve any data. After adding json i can't retrieve or send data...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: data.testId & data.testAge do not return there respective values from update.php

Answer (score 3):

I think the $.ajax function would be better suited to your needs:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/scripts/update.php",
    data: {id: testId, age: testAge},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        $(".testDiv").html(data['testId']);
        $(".testDiv2").html(data['testAge']);
    }
});
```

Your PHP script would stay the same. I am providing the code due to the fact that 
you gave very little information on what error you were receiving. As camus said already please provide more information on what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing `data.testId`, That means you are accessing the response (stored in a variable called data in your example) you received from the update.php as a result for your jQuery post call. By mentioning the datatype as `jSon`, you are making sure that the response from server will be converted to jSon format.

If your update.php page is returning a jSon like this

```
{ "id": "3","age":"53"}
```

Then you can access the indidual values like `data.id` and `data.age`.

The below code should work if you have a valid json returning from the server page like above

```
$.post("/scripts/update.php", {  id: testId, age: testAge}, dataType:"json",function(data) {
   $(.testDiv).html(data.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do what @gimg1 said, but like this:

```
var form_data = {
            testId: $("#testIdForm").val(),
            testAge: $("#testAgeForm").val()
        };
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/scripts/update.php",
    data: {id: testId, age: testAge},
    dataType: form_data,
    success: function(response) {
        if(response == 'success'){
            //do success function here
        }
    }
});
```